# If “I Will!” vs “I’ll!”

Tags: contractions

I told my friend “Enjoy your coffee.” and she answered “I’ll!”  It took me a second to realise it was “I will!” Why is the first one wrong and the second version not? I know it’s wrong but I don’t know why.

Thanks.